# Is there a way to use StopSpeakingAsync on SpeechSynthesizer without Dispose hanging?

Tags: text-to-speech, com-interop, azure-cognitive-services, safehandle

When trying to use SpeechSynthesizer from the Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech sdk, I noticed that Dispose() hangs if it gets called after StopSpeakingAsync has been called.

Is there a way to circumvent this? I did a short console app that illustrates the problem below. I used Reflector to try to understand what was going on inside the library but only found out that it seems to be `SpxExceptionThrower.LogErrorIfFail` that hangs.

I'm using version 1.18.0 of the sdk.

(Note that it is necessary to have a Cognitive Services/Speech Services subscription and enter the key and region into the `.FromSubscription` call)

Thanks!

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("your-own-subscription-key", "your-region");
    var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config);
    var task = synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync("Some long speech that keeps going on forever and ever and ever...");
    task.Wait(2000);
    await synthesizer.StopSpeakingAsync();
    synthesizer.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("This line will never be reached");
}
```

```
// Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.InteropSafeHandle

protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
{
   if (this.releaseHandleFunc != null)
   {
      // LogErrorIfFail appears to hang
      SpxExceptionThrower.LogErrorIfFail(this.releaseHandleFunc(base.handle));
      this.releaseHandleFunc = null;
      base.handle = IntPtr.Zero;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am an engineer working on the SDK. Could you tell me the SDK you are using? And maybe you can share me the [log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-loggin)

Comment: Hi! Sure, I'm using the latest stable version: 1.18.0. The log file is [here](https://pastebin.com/PZcVE1Nb).

Comment: OK thanks! Seems this is a bug, and we will look into it. As a workaround, you can wait `StopSpeakingAsync()` finished (not using `await`) before disposing the synthesizer.